# Does L1 or L2 regularization give the most sparse weights for the same loss function and optimizer?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, lasso-regression, regularized

If I consider a dataset, which regularization technique (L1 regularization or L2 regularization) will output the highest sparse weights for the same loss function and same optimizer?

Comment: L1 (Lasso)  will push for sparser weights by definition but that doesn't mean it will perform better than the L2. It's truly depending on the loss function and the used model (as some models have hard time to learn with many features e.g SVM)

Answer (score 0):

By definition, L1 regularization (lasso) forces some weights to zero, thus leading to sparser solutions; according to the Wikipedia entry on [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)#Regularizers_for_sparsity):

> It can be shown that the L1 norm induces sparsity

See also the [L1 and L2 Regularization Methods](https://towardsdatascience.com/l1-and-l2-regularization-methods-ce25e7fc831c) post at Towards Data Science:

> The **key difference** between these techniques is that Lasso shrinks the less important feature’s coefficient to zero thus, removing some feature altogether. So, this works well for **feature selection** in case we have a huge number of features.

For more details, see the following threads @ Cross Validated:

[Sparsity in Lasso and advantage over ridge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151954/sparsity-in-lasso-and-advantage-over-ridge-statistical-learning)

[Why does the Lasso provide Variable Selection?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74542/why-does-the-lasso-provide-variable-selection)

Answer (score -1):

In machine learning, when comparing L1 (Lasso) and L2 (Ridge) regularization techniques for the same loss function and optimizer, L1 regularization typically results in sparser weights. This is due to the fundamental difference in how these regularization techniques penalize the weights of the model.

L1 Regularization (Lasso): This approach adds the absolute value of the coefficients as a penalty term to the loss function. The key characteristic of L1 regularization is its ability to shrink less important feature's coefficients to zero, thus effectively performing feature selection. This property leads to sparsity, meaning that the model will have a number of its coefficients exactly equal to zero.

L2 Regularization (Ridge): In contrast, L2 regularization adds the square of the coefficients as the penalty term. This technique tends to shrink the coefficients towards zero but does not set them to zero. Instead, all coefficients are reduced by some amount, but they remain non-zero, which means L2 regularization does not inherently produce sparse models.

The reason behind the sparsity in L1 regularization is its geometric interpretation: the L1 penalty has diamond-shaped contours, which often intersect with the error surface at an axis, leading to a coefficient being exactly zero. In contrast, the L2 penalty has circular contours, which are less likely to intersect with axes, thus not promoting sparsity.

When comparing models with the same loss function and optimizer, and if the goal is to achieve a sparse model where some coefficients are exactly zero, L1 regularization is generally the preferred choice. However, it's important to remember that the choice between L1 and L2 regularization should also be based on the specific context and requirements of the model and data at hand.